# 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable' error in python search?

Tags: python, search, typeerror

I am trying to write a search function on python, that searches for a customer ID in a database (for a login feature) here is the code:

```
def search_ID():

import sqlite3 # imports SQlite library
new_db = sqlite3.connect('LightningParties.db')
c = new_db.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM Customer_Details WHERE ID=?",(CustomerIDSave,)) 

results = c.fetchall # fetches all of the ID's not just one

for row in results:
    forename1 = (column[1])
```

Anytime I try and run this i keep getting this error:

```
File "F:/stuff that actually works/customer_login.py", line 29, in search_ID 
for row in results: TypeError: 
'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

How do i fix this? any help would be gladly apprecaited

Comment: Tip: when you have an error message that refers to a line number, indicate which line of the posted code it's referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding parens:

```
results = c.fetchall()
```

You're assigning the method when you should be *running* the method and assigning what it returns.